# Change value of a textarea using flask-wtforms

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using `flask-wtforms` to create a Textarea.

```
body = TextAreaField('body')
```

I want to change the value of the textarea which you can do in html like this.

```
<textarea>other value then default</textarea>
```

How can I integrate this with flask-wtforms?

My template looks like this:

```
{{ form.body(rows="20") }} <!--texarea -->
```

With a simple input field I could do something like this:

```
{{ form.body(value="other value then default") }} <!-- input field -->
```

I need to set the default value in the template itself. Because it will have info over the article the page is about.

Answer (score 8):

Weird that 2 years after this question was asked, there's still no standard way to implement this.

What I do is write it out in plain HTML:

```
<textarea id="body" name="body">{{ value }}</textarea>
```

This works fine and the textarea is validated normally

Answer (score 0):

With TextArea you have to use the `default` value so it renders with that.

```
body = TextAreaField('body', default='Some other value')
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get set the value in the template instead of in the form code?

Comment: Please add some explanation of the code. Code-only answers are usually not useful on their own.

Comment: Thanks AndyG, fixed. Tristan T, I'm not sure, I've never done it in the template, however, I'd advice to keep it in the python code. As it's very likely that the form will often be sent using default values, setting the default values in the form prevents from having to look for those default values in a different file.

Comment: I need it in the template because when you ask for it there needs to be an article to get the body from. So putting it in the template would be far more logical then hacking something into the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a widget that defines an entire alternative html behavior, like so:

in widgets.py

```
from markupsafe import Markup
from wtforms.widgets import html_params


class BodyWidget(object):
    data_template = (
        '<textarea %(text)s >other value then default</textarea>'
    )

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("id", field.id)
        kwargs.setdefault("name", field.name)
        template = self.data_template
        return Markup(
            template % {"text": html_params(type="text", value=(field.data or ""), rows=20, cols=50, **kwargs)}
        )
```

in forms.py

```
from widgets import BodyWidget

body = TextAreaField('body', widget=BodyWidget())
```

Answer (score -1):

I used kind of a hack. Using javascript to set the value of the textarea.

```
<script>document.getElementById('body-input').value="other value then default";</script>
```

Although not optimal, it works.